# Subtracting a point in elliptic curve cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I've had lots of practice adding points for my crypto class. However I've run into a situation where I need to subtract two points for decryption:

```
Pm + kPb - nb(kG) = Pm
```

Where Pm is the plaintext, Pb is participant b's public key, nb is participant b's private key, G is a base point in the elliptic group Ep(a,b), and k is a random positive integer chosen by participant a.

I am able to compute nb(kG) and kPb, but I'm unsure how to subtract the two. How is this done?

Comment: Adding the inverse of nbkG, i.e., -nbkG, to the point (Pm+kbP)?

Comment: How do I calculate an inverse point?

Comment: You may use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) as a strating point for arithmetics on elliptic curves.

Answer (score 14):

The inverse of a point $P = (x_P,y_P)$ is its reflexion across the $x$-axis : $P' = (x_P,-y_P)$.

If you want to compute $Q-P$, just replace $y_P$ by $-y_P$ in the usual formula for point addition.

Comment: Thanks! Should -yp be taken mod P?

Comment: ConditionRacer: Yes. You should take -yp mod P.