# Ed25519 with R replaced by H(RAM)?

Tags: signature, ed25519

Ed25519 signatures consist of $(R, s)$, where $s = r + H(RAM)a$ $mod$ $l$, and $R = rB$. This differs from the [Schnorr signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) where instead of $R$, the signature contains the hash $h=H(RAM)$. According to [the Elligator paper](http://elligator.cr.yp.to/papers.html) (page 5) "one can reconstruct $(h, s)$ from $(R, s)$ and vice versa".

I see that $(R, s) => (h, s)$ is trivial, but how would one derive $(R, s)$ from $(h, s)$?

Or more generally, how would the verification equation look like with $(h, s)$ as the signature?

(Motivation: I'd like to use $(h, s)$ as the signature to get indistinguishability from random numbers without needing the Elligator 2 map. Probably means no bulk verification, but that's not needed for what I'm thinking about.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, I believe that you can simply compute $R = s*B - h*A$ using [point subtraction](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11316/subtracting-a-point-in-elliptic-curve-cryptography).

Comment: I guess you then just compare $h$ to $H((sB-hA)AM)$ for verification?

Comment: I had to do $R = -(h*A-s*B)$ instead. Seems weird, but I think has to do with the modulus $l$. I'll have to figure it out. Pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you post the numbers you are using?

Comment: Link below. It's the ed25519.py from ed25519.cr.yp.to with minimal changes. Switching the commented lines in checkvalid makes the signature no longer pass. https://gist.github.com/jvarho/0d654fdfb26d0cb2f4cb