# Could the reversibility of adding function be considered a weakness to secp256k1?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have just started studying cryptography and secp256k1. I just wonder that adding two points can be easily reversible when the generator point is publicly known.

I mean that if $Q=\operatorname{adding}(P, R)$ then we can calculate $P$ as $\operatorname{adding}(Q, R)$, am I right? Would this be considered a weakness? I am not sure if there exists a known reverse function for doubling as well, Something that could recover P with having Q from $Q=\operatorname{doubling}(P)$.

Anyways, what point is the major strength of secp256k1? Does that rely on the functions we choose for adding and doubling? Or maybe it relies on the nature of the $IF$ statement we use in the calculations?

Taking any arbitrary functions $Q =f(P)$ and $Q=g(P, R)$ and then performing the multiplication function as long as the multiplication function is Surjective and Injective over the field $F_p$, will we get the same level of security?

Comment: realated [Subtracting a point in elliptic curve cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11316/subtracting-a-point-in-elliptic-curve-cryptography)

Comment: Ae you asking whether $Q = P+G$ implies $P=Q+G$? Of course not, unless $G = \mathcal O$ or $G$ has order $2$.

Comment: If a line intersects the elliptic curve in exactly 3 points why should not we conclude that if $Q=P+G$ then $P=Q+G$!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Q=\operatorname{adding}(P,R)=P+R$, then $P$ can be computed from $Q$ and $R$ as $P=\operatorname{adding}(Q,-R)=Q+(-R)$ where $-R$ is easy to compute from $R$ (just change the $y$ coordinate of $R$ from $y_R$ to $p-y_R$ where $p$ is the order of the prime field). This property follows from $\operatorname{adding}$ being a [group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Group_law).

If $Q=\operatorname{doubling}(P)=P+P=2\times P$, then we can efficiently compute $P$ from $Q$. One method is to use that $P=\displaystyle\frac{n+1}2\times Q$ (where $n$ is the order of the curve's group). This property follows from $n$ being odd.

Neither property is considered weakness, because it follows from having a group (of odd order), which is necessary for the applications thought, including ECDSA.

By definition of `secp256k1`, for that curve $p=2^{256}-2^{32}-977$ and $n=2^{256}-432420386565659656852420866394968145599$.

---

> What is the major strength of secp256k1?

It forms with point addition a group of known 256-bit prime order $n$ with a generator $G$, such that we do not know an algorithm requiring much less than $\sqrt n$ steps to compute $a$ from $a\times G$, for random $a$ in $\Bbb Z_n^*$ ([Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)).
<sub>Note per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/145667): $G+G=2\times G$ in a group noted additively becomes $G*G=G^2$ in that same group noted multiplicatively. Similarly $Q=a\times G$ in a group noted additively becomes $Q=G^a$ in that same group noted multiplicatively. This is why solving either equation for $a$ is called the Discrete Logarithm Problem in the group considered.</sub>

More strongly, we know no algorithm requiring much less than $\sqrt n$ steps to tell sizably better than random if a triple what obtained as $(a\times G,b\times G,c\times G)$ or as $(a\times G,b\times G,ab\times G)$ for random $a$, $b$, $c$ in $\Bbb Z_n$ ([Decisional Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption) assumption).

`secp256k1` is preferred over simpler groups with the same properties, notably [Schnorr groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group), because a point can be expressed much more compactly and the group law is much faster. `secp256k1` is preferred over other groups with the same properties also built by point addition on an elliptic curve over a prime field, notably `secp256r1`, because the special form of $p$ for `secp256k1` allows slightly faster calculation, with no known decisive drawback.

---

> Does that rely on the functions we choose for adding and doubling?

Yes it has to do with the group and its law, that is *the functions we choose for adding and doubling*.

> Taking any arbitrary functions $Q=f(P)$ and $Q=g(P,R)$ and then performing the multiplication function as long as the multiplication function is Surjective and Injective over the field $\Bbb F_p$, will we get the same level of security?

No, even with added constraints making the operation defined by $f$ and $g$ a finite group law. As a counterexample, take the group $(\Bbb Z_p,+)$ for some prime $p$: that defines point doubling $f$, point addition $g$, and we can take any non-zero element as $G$ with $n=p$. Point multiplication reduces to multiplication modulo $p$. That allows construction of the group as stated, yet the DLP is trivial, giving no security: given $Q=a\times G$ we can compute $a$ as $(G^{-1}\bmod p)\times Q$ where $G^{-1}\bmod p$ can be computed by the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Note: When restricted to point addition and doubling as in an axiomatic construction from $f$ and $g$, we can compute $-R$ as $(n-1)\times R$.

Comment: Minor correction: $(a \times G, b \times G, ab \times G)$

Comment: Would you please explain little more on how is this special multiplication is related to the discrete logarithm problem!?

Comment: If $Q=axG$ what discrete logarithm problem should I solve to recover $a$!?